# The answer to this puzzle is a three letter word

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

Easy riddle. Even kids should be able to get this.

> In the end, the answer to this puzzle is a three letter word and also a single
>   letter.

[image]

Ignore the Excel sheet lines

Hint

> Each row is a clue which in total creates a full clue
>
> Hint 2
>
> First line "Numbers" from different languages (Hindi, Japanese, etc)
>
> Second Line: Anagram of Played

Comment: You know you can remove Excel gridlines by going to the View tab and unticking the 'Gridlines' checkbox in the 'Show' section? Top tip :)

Comment: rot13 (puebab, byq, lbhat, ->ntr)?

Comment: Not there @Archipelago

Comment: rot13 (fbzrguvat jvgu "zna"? Urzvatjnl: Byq zna naq gur frn, Arvy Lbhat: fbhaqgenpx sbe Qrnq Zna?

Comment: jung jnf Arvy Lbhat'f snzbhf fbat?

Comment: Should this puzzle have a rebus tag?

Comment: @DEEM As though there's just one?

Comment: He had a song almost the same title : rot13(byq zna

Comment: Does the underscore on the beginning of the 3rd cell have a purpose?

Comment: Yes @Marvin. Word/s that precede all three words mentioned?

Comment: Did you intend to spoiler tag the hints?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> "Tea
> as in first box Every word is missing with T
> and Tea is three letter word and even single letter.

Comment: Can you explain how this applies to the rest of the clues?

Answer (score 2):

Four different rows

> NUMBERS

Second row

> PLAYED

Third row

> BY THIS     (fits all three words By this logic, By this time, By this date)

Fourth row

> OLD MAN   ( Common to both Hemingway and Neil Young- and the pix are of old man :) )

Combining

> Numbers played by this old man ( Nursery Rhyme) 
>
>  TEN or X (Roman)